# Does ironpython have libraries that replace the pywin32 extensions?

Tags: .net, com, ironpython

I have some old python code that uses the pywin32 extensions. Starting out with .net, I would like to port it to ironpython.

The old python code uses things like pythoncom.com_error, pywintypes.Time and interfaces a COM module that implements the IDispatch interface.

Does the .net libraries of ironpython have all I need for communicating with the COM module?
Specifically, does it have something to replace com_error and Time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own post.. :-)

1. com_error may be replaced by System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
2. The pywintypes.Time may be replaced by System.DateTime, (DATE in IDispatch interface)

Still, if anybody knows about any good documentation on IronPython, COM interoperability and moving from pywin32 to .net, please respond..